# postfix problems with pattern in virtual file

Tags: postfix

We are trying to forward all emails to a specific email address. I think everything is set up okay, such as 'main.cf' and 'virtual-regexp' files. If we put the following in the 'virtual' file, the forwarding works correctly:

@ourmail.com mainid@ourmail.com

However, if we try to use the following in 'virtual' to send ALL email to the ID, it ignores it and sends it to the original user:

(.*) mainid@ourmail.com

We got the idea for the above from the following question and answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18270439/postfix-2-9-6-1-forward-all-mail-to-an-external-mail-address

Any ideas why the pattern '(.*)' doesn't work? We've tried so many different patterns that our heads are starting to spin.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue. You need to complete the steps listed above, but in addition you need to comment out the following lines in main.cf (if they are there) before restarting the postfix process:

```
#virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
#virtual_alias_domains = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
```